# How to delete variables with huge percent of missings in table in SAS?

Tags: sas, missing-data, proc-sql, 4gl

I have table in SAS with missing values like below:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | ... | coln
-----|------|------|-----|-------
111  |      | abc  | ... | abc
222  | 11   | C1   | ... | 11
333  | 18   |      | ... | 12
...  | ...  | ...  | ... | ...
```

And I need to delete from above table variables where is more than 80% missing values (>=80%).

How can I do taht in SAS ?

Comment: Check out this answer from Reeza: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Calculate-percent-missing-in-long-dataset/td-p/499995

Comment: Stu Sztukowski I saw this post but it does not work for me, I do not know why, but it generate only 1 row in output, maybe do you have other solution ? :)

Comment: Are all of the variables you want to potentially drop numeric?  Or do you also need to test some that are character strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro below will create a macro variable named `&drop_vars` that holds a list of variables to drop from your dataset that exceed missing threshold. This works for both character and numeric variables. If you have a *ton* of them then this macro will fail but it can easily be modified to handle any number of variables. You can save and reuse this macro.

```
%macro get_missing_vars(lib=, dsn=, threshold=);
    %global drop_vars;

    /* Generate a select statement that calculates the proportion missing:
       nmiss(var1)/count(*) as var1, nmiss(var2)/count(*) as var2, ... */   
    proc sql noprint;
        select cat('nmiss(', strip(name), ')/count(*) as ', strip(name) )
        into :calculate_pct_missing separated by ','
        from dictionary.columns
        where     libname = upcase("&lib")
              AND memname = upcase("&dsn")
        ;
    quit;

    /* Calculate the percent missing */
    proc sql;
        create table pct_missing as
            select &calculate_pct_missing.
            from &lib..&dsn.
        ;
    quit;

    /* Convert to a long table */
    proc transpose data=pct_missing out=drop_list;
        var _NUMERIC_;
    run;

    /* Get a list of variables to drop that are >= the drop threshold */
    proc sql noprint;
        select _NAME_
        into :drop_vars separated by ' '
        from drop_list
        where COL1 GE &threshold.
        ;
    quit;
%mend;
```

It has three parameters:

`lib`: Library of your dataset

`dsn`: Dataset name without the library

`threshold`: Proportion of missing values a variable must meet or exceed to be dropped

For example, let's generate some sample data and use this. `col1 col2 col3` all have 80% missing values.

```
data have;
    array col[10];
    do i = 1 to 10;
        do j = 1 to 10;
            col[j] = i;
            if(i > 2 AND j in(1, 2, 3) ) then col[j] = .;
        end;
        
        output;
    end;

    drop i j;
run;
```

We'll run the macro and check the log:

```
%get_missing_vars(lib=work, dsn=have, threshold=0.8);

%put &drop_vars;
```

The log shows:

```
col1 col2 col3
```

Now we can pass this into a simple data step.

```
data want;
    set have;
    drop &drop_vars;
run;
```

Comment: Nice work! I also suggest to use `%if %str(&drop_vars) %then %do; ...; %end;` to surround `drop ...` statement.